# Unable to load Datatable array of object

Tags: jquery, datatable

[image]

I m trying to load datatable after ajax Call to the API, I got my array of object but nothing is loading. Any Help?

```
  $.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: origin + "/api/costi-produzione/" + postUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (obj, textstatus) {

            $('#datatable').DataTable({
                'data': obj.costiProduzione,
                'columns': [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "NIA1" },
                { "data": "NIA2" },
                { "data": "NIA3" }, 
                { "data": "id" }
                ]
            });


    },
    error: function (obj, textstatus) {
        alert(obj.msg);
    }
  });
```

Comment: whoch datatables are you using? is it this one? https://datatables.net/

Comment: Yes i m using that one

Comment: console.log obj after ajax call on success function and see the output

Answer (score 0):

The code was right!!! Wrond Datatable #id selector ahah